# Material UI dropdown/autocomplete

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When trying to put a label with a dropdown in material UI for some reason I am seeing this behavior [image]

For some reason I can't make them aligned at the same row.

This is my component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        display: 'flex',
    },
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
      },
    selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

function DutPreferencesTab(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const {data} = props
    console.log(data)
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setAge(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', direction: 'row'}}>
             <CustomLabel  text={'Relay:'}  variant={"subtitle1"} />
                     <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                         <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
                         <Select
                         labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                         id="demo-simple-select"
                         value={age}
                         onChange={handleChange}
                         >
                         <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                         <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                         <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                         </Select>
                     </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CustomLabel.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';

function CustomLabel({text, variant, styles}) {
    return (
        <div className={clsx(styles)}>
            <Typography variant={variant} gutterBottom>
                {text}
            </Typography>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CustomLabel
```

I tried everything but still I can't make them align at the same row and I can't figure our why. It appears to only happen with dropdowns as far as I saw. I have other texts that are perfectly aligned with the label.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You could try `flex-wrap: nowrap` in the container's style

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the element being inspected so that it's clear how they are sitting next to each other?

Comment: This is what you are looking for - https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-paper-yuull?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SarunUK It worked thanks! can you explain how the flex-end works here?

Comment: `align-items` with `flex-start`, `center`, `flex-end` etc. will control the alignment of items inside the flex container.

Comment: I believe in the codesandbox you need to change the direction property to flexDirection,

Answer (score 1):

If you highlight the elements in dev tools, you will see that they are aligned. The problem is just that the `Select` is much taller than the label and by default the tops of the elements are aligned (actually the elements are stretched to be the same height, but this has the effect of lining them up at the top).

[image: Select highlighted in dev tools]

When you select an item and the label in the `Select` (e.g. "Age") moves up, you can more easily see why it is so tall.

[image: Select with selected item highlighted in dev tools]

The solution is to modify the `align-items` CSS property on the div that wraps the label and the select. A value of `baseline` seems to be the best option in this case.

[image: Lined up using align-items baseline]

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import CustomLabel from "./CustomLabel";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    alignItems: "baseline",
    display: "flex"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  }
}));

export default function DutPreferencesTab(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CustomLabel text={"Relay:"} variant={"subtitle1"} />
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit flex align-items]

Related Flexbox resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#align-items

Comment: baseline does not work for me but flex-end does work. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Baseline works in my example, so I would have to see a sandbox reproducing your problem with baseline in order to determine what difference is causing a problem.